# WSO2IS 5.10.0 - Error while loading user profile metadata with multiple user-store

Tags: active-directory, wso2, wso2-identity-server

For a client, we need to configure multiple Active-Directory user-store inside WSO2IS 5.10.0.
For that we have configured 3 Active-Directory secondary user-stores (primary user-store is a jdbc store). They are all connected to the same Active-Directory server, but with a different `User Search Base`.
We also defined all claims we needed (all user-stores have the same claims configured).

Let say we have 3 secondary user-stores named A, B and C.

When we go to user list page, no problem, we can see all user loaded from all the secondary user-store.
When we want to see user details from the user-store C, no problem. I can also edit the user without any problems.

Then, if we want to see details from a user coming from user-store A or B, we have the following error displayed oin the WSO2IS web interface :

> Error while loading user profile metadata

With the following logs in wso2carbon.log:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:08,494] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.UserIdResolverCache} - Cache: user_id_from_user_name_cache which is under USER_ID_RESOLVER_CACHE_MANAGER, doesn't contain the key: AD-COMPANY/someName@company.fr
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:08,504] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LDAPConnectionContext} - LDAP connection circuit breaker state: close, so trying to obtain the LDAP connection, connection URL: ldaps://XX.XX.XX.XX:636
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:08,658] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Listing users with Property: mail SearchFilter: (&(&(objectClass=user)(!(sn=Service)))(mail=someName@company.fr))
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:08,658] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Searching for user with SearchFilter: (&(&(objectClass=user)(!(sn=Service)))(mail=someName@company.fr)) in SearchBase:
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:08,658] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :objectGuid
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:08,659] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :sn
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:08,659] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Listing users. SearchBase: OU=COMPANY,DC=companysiege,DC=local Constructed-Filter: (&(&(objectClass=user)(!(sn=Service)))(mail=someName@company.fr))
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:08,659] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Search controls. Max Limit: 100 Max Time: 10000
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:08,659] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LDAPConnectionContext} - LDAP connection circuit breaker state: close, so trying to obtain the LDAP connection, connection URL: ldaps://XX.XX.XX.XX:636
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:08,824] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - objectGuid : 2901506c-f5e4-4185-bac6-2e56d445b1ee
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:08,828] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - result: 2901506c-f5e4-4185-bac6-2e56d445b1ee
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:08,830] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.UserIdResolverCache} - Cache: user_id_from_user_name_cache which is under USER_ID_RESOLVER_CACHE_MANAGER,added the entry: 2901506c-f5e4-4185-bac6-2e56d445b1ee for the key: AD-COMPANY/someName@company.fr successfully
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:08,830] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.UserIdResolverCache} - Cache: user_name_from_user_id_cache which is under USER_ID_RESOLVER_CACHE_MANAGER,added the entry: AD-COMPANY/someName@company.fr for the key: 2901506c-f5e4-4185-bac6-2e56d445b1ee successfully
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:08,838] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LDAPConnectionContext} - LDAP connection circuit breaker state: close, so trying to obtain the LDAP connection, connection URL: ldaps://XX.XX.XX.XX:636
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,013] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Listing users with Property: objectGuid SearchFilter: (&(&(objectClass=user)(!(sn=Service)))(objectGuid=\6c\50\01\29\e4\f5\85\41\ba\c6\2e\56\d4\45\b1\ee))
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,013] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Searching for user with SearchFilter: (&(&(objectClass=user)(!(sn=Service)))(objectGuid=\6c\50\01\29\e4\f5\85\41\ba\c6\2e\56\d4\45\b1\ee)) in SearchBase:
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,014] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :mail
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,014] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :sn
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,014] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Listing users. SearchBase: OU=COMPANY,DC=companysiege,DC=local Constructed-Filter: (&(&(objectClass=user)(!(sn=Service)))(objectGuid=\6c\50\01\29\e4\f5\85\41\ba\c6\2e\56\d4\45\b1\ee))
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,014] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Search controls. Max Limit: 100 Max Time: 10000
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,014] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LDAPConnectionContext} - LDAP connection circuit breaker state: close, so trying to obtain the LDAP connection, connection URL: ldaps://XX.XX.XX.XX:636
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,183] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - mail : someName@company.fr
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,189] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - result: someName@company.fr
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,190] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Using default configurations for the user DN cache, having search base : OU=COMPANY,DC=companysiege,DC=local
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,190] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LDAPConnectionContext} - LDAP connection circuit breaker state: close, so trying to obtain the LDAP connection, connection URL: ldaps://XX.XX.XX.XX:636
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,355] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Searching for user with SearchFilter: (&(objectClass=user)(mail=someName@company.fr)) in SearchBase:
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,356] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :role
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,356] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :mail
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,356] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :accountLock
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,356] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :extensionAttribute2
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,356] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :extensionAttribute1
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,356] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :lastLogonTimestamp
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,356] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :extensionAttribute4
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,357] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :assistant
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,357] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :extensionAttribute3
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,357] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :postalCode
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,357] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :givenName
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,357] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :mobile
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,368] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :extensionAttribute5
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,369] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :co
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,369] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :title
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,371] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :l
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,371] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :division
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,371] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :postalAddress
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,372] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :streetAddress
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,372] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :objectGuid
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,372] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :profileConfiguration
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,373] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :sn
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,374] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :pwdLastSet
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,393] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager} - Active Directory timestamp attributes: [whenCreated, whenChanged]
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,394] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager} - Retrieved user store properties before type conversions: {mail=someName@company.fr, lastLogonTimestamp=132573386460398774, postalCode=69321, objectGuid=2901506c-f5e4-4185-bac6-2e56d445b1ee, sn=someName, co=France, l=Lyon cedex 05, pwdLastSet=129666859129668524}
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,394] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager} - Converted timestamp attribute values: {}
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,394] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager} - Retrieved user store properties after type conversions: {mail=someName@company.fr, lastLogonTimestamp=132573386460398774, postalCode=69321, objectGuid=2901506c-f5e4-4185-bac6-2e56d445b1ee, sn=someName, co=France, l=Lyon cedex 05, pwdLastSet=129666859129668524}
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,395] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.UserUniqueIDDomainResolver} - Cache miss for user id: 2901506c-f5e4-4185-bac6-2e56d445b1ee searching from the database.
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,405] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - Listing users who having value as 2901506c-f5e4-4185-bac6-2e56d445b1ee for the claim http://wso2.org/claims/userid
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,405] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - Pre listener user list: [] for domain: null
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,406] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - No domain name found in claim value. Searching through all user stores for possible matches
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,407] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - Invoking the get user list for domain: AD-COMPANY for claim: http://wso2.org/claims/userid value: AD-COMPANY/2901506c-f5e4-4185-bac6-2e56d445b1ee
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,408] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - Listing users who having value as AD-COMPANY/2901506c-f5e4-4185-bac6-2e56d445b1ee for the claim http://wso2.org/claims/userid
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,426] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - Pre listener user list: [] for domain: AD-COMPANY
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,426] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - Domain found in claim value. Searching only in the AD-COMPANY for possible matches
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,427] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LDAPConnectionContext} - LDAP connection circuit breaker state: close, so trying to obtain the LDAP connection, connection URL: ldaps://XX.XX.XX.XX:636
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,592] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Listing users with Property: objectGuid SearchFilter: (&(&(objectClass=user)(!(sn=Service)))(objectGuid=\6c\50\01\29\e4\f5\85\41\ba\c6\2e\56\d4\45\b1\ee))
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,596] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Searching for user with SearchFilter: (&(&(objectClass=user)(!(sn=Service)))(objectGuid=\6c\50\01\29\e4\f5\85\41\ba\c6\2e\56\d4\45\b1\ee)) in SearchBase:
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,596] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :objectGuid
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,596] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :sn
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,596] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Listing users. SearchBase: OU=COMPANY,DC=companysiege,DC=local Constructed-Filter: (&(&(objectClass=user)(!(sn=Service)))(objectGuid=\6c\50\01\29\e4\f5\85\41\ba\c6\2e\56\d4\45\b1\ee))
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,596] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Search controls. Max Limit: 100 Max Time: 10000
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,600] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LDAPConnectionContext} - LDAP connection circuit breaker state: close, so trying to obtain the LDAP connection, connection URL: ldaps://XX.XX.XX.XX:636
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,764] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - objectGuid : 2901506c-f5e4-4185-bac6-2e56d445b1ee
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,769] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - result: 2901506c-f5e4-4185-bac6-2e56d445b1ee
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,771] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - List of filtered users for: AD-COMPANY : [[2901506c-f5e4-4185-bac6-2e56d445b1ee]]
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,771] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.UserUniqueIDDomainResolver} - Cache miss for user id: 2901506c-f5e4-4185-bac6-2e56d445b1ee searching from the database.
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,772] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.UserIdResolverCache} - Cache: user_name_from_user_id_cache which is under USER_ID_RESOLVER_CACHE_MANAGER, found the entry: AD-COMPANY/someName@company.fr for
the key: 2901506c-f5e4-4185-bac6-2e56d445b1ee successfully.
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,774] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - Users from user store: AD-COMPANY : [someName@company.fr]
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,774] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - Post listener user list: [someName@company.fr] for domain: AD-COMPANY
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,781] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - Secondary user list for domain: AD-COMPANY : [org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.User@d33c5fe5]
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,782] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - Invoking the get user list for domain: AD-UNION-COMPANY for claim: http://wso2.org/claims/userid value: AD-UNION-COMPANY/2901506c-f5e4-4185-bac6-2e56d445b1ee
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,782] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - Listing users who having value as AD-UNION-COMPANY/2901506c-f5e4-4185-bac6-2e56d445b1ee for the claim http://wso2.org/claims/userid
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,794] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - Pre listener user list: [] for domain: AD-UNION-COMPANY
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,794] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - Domain found in claim value. Searching only in the AD-UNION-COMPANY for possible matches
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,795] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LDAPConnectionContext} - LDAP connection circuit breaker state: close, so trying to obtain the LDAP connection, connection URL: ldaps://XX.XX.XX.XX:636
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,956] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Listing users with Property: objectGuid SearchFilter: (&(&(objectClass=user)(!(sn=Service)))(objectGuid=\6c\50\01\29\e4\f5\85\41\ba\c6\2e\56\d4\45\b1\ee))
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,957] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Searching for user with SearchFilter: (&(&(objectClass=user)(!(sn=Service)))(objectGuid=\6c\50\01\29\e4\f5\85\41\ba\c6\2e\56\d4\45\b1\ee)) in SearchBase:
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,957] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :objectGuid
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,957] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Requesting attribute :sn
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,957] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Listing users. SearchBase: OU=COMPANY,DC=companysiege,DC=local Constructed-Filter: (&(&(objectClass=user)(!(sn=Service)))(objectGuid=\6c\50\01\29\e4\f5\85\41\ba\c6\2e\56\d4\45\b1\ee))
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,957] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Search controls. Max Limit: 100 Max Time: 10000
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:09,958] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LDAPConnectionContext} - LDAP connection circuit breaker state: close, so trying to obtain the LDAP connection, connection URL: ldaps://XX.XX.XX.XX:636
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:10,107] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - objectGuid : 2901506c-f5e4-4185-bac6-2e56d445b1ee
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:10,111] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.UniqueIDReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - result: 2901506c-f5e4-4185-bac6-2e56d445b1ee
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:10,112] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - List of filtered users for: AD-UNION-COMPANY : [[2901506c-f5e4-4185-bac6-2e56d445b1ee]]
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:10,112] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.UserUniqueIDDomainResolver} - Cache miss for user id: 2901506c-f5e4-4185-bac6-2e56d445b1ee searching from the database.
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:10,113] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.UserIdResolverCache} - Cache: user_name_from_user_id_cache which is under USER_ID_RESOLVER_CACHE_MANAGER, found the entry: AD-COMPANY/someName@company.fr for the key: 2901506c-f5e4-4185-bac6-2e56d445b1ee successfully.
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:10,115] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - Users from user store: AD-UNION-COMPANY : [someName@company.fr]
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:10,116] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - Post listener user list: [someName@company.fr] for domain: AD-UNION-COMPANY
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:10,116] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - Secondary user list for domain: AD-UNION-COMPANY : [org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.User@d33c5fe5]
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:10,117] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} - Post listener user list: [AD-COMPANY/someName@company.fr, AD-COMPANY/someName@company.fr] for domain: null
TID: [-1234] [] [2021-02-16 15:06:10,133] [b1f238e2-d510-4e2f-9031-562703683f99] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.profile.ui.client.UserProfileCient} - org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.profile.stub.UserProfileMgtServiceUserProfileExceptionException: UserProfileMgtServiceUserProfileExceptionException
```

Now if we disable user-store C from WSO2IS web interface, we can see user detail from user-store B and edit them without any problem (so I suppose, no configuration problem here).
And of course, if we also disable user-store B, user-store A work.

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Perhaps the internal LDAP context get confused having same connection URL. Can you try having different host-name for the same LDAP server and configure the connection URL with hostnames for user stores A, B and C ?

Comment: As you suggested @RuwanAbeykoon, I have setup 3 different host-name for the same LDAP server. Then edit user-store configuration and restart WSO2IS but the issue is still here.